# Is a snubber diode the correct solution? Preventing overload protection faults

Tags: batteries, diodes, lithium-ion, protection, flyback

I have been troubleshooting a strange problem for a while now and I think I've settled on the right solution.

I have an off-the-shelf 12v lithium-ion battery (12v 10A max output) with integrated over-voltage, reverse polarity, and over-current protection circuit that I use for camping, etc. I have confirmed that the supply is not the problem with various other devices.

When I connect my 12 V shower to it (12 V 8 A Max Draw), it will power on and run without issue. However, when you switch it off using the inline switch, it will trip the battery packs protection circuit. If you simply pull the plug out it will not trip the protection circuit. Speaking with the supplier of both products this is something they have seen before with this specific combination. I'm fairly certain this is due to the flyback voltage from the motor shutting off causing the protection circuit to trip. I intend to add a snub circuit/flyback diode to the wiring for the shower to prevent this.

Please let me know if this is the right/wrong solution. Assistance in selecting the right diode would also be appreciated.

(Sincerely, mechanical engineering student dabbling with 12 V electronics).

Comment: Perhaps ading only a serial diode ?

Comment: Full schematics of the device and shower unit please. Please provide links to the supplier's documents including copies of correspondence regarding what they said about "something they have seen before with this specific combination" and finally, (and fundamentally most important), what do they recommend you do?

Comment: Schematics of the battery protection circuit are unavailable unfortunately. Only details I was able to source from manufacturer was that 10A is the overload protection parameter. Supplier was unable to provide a solution. For detail, this specific battery and pump switch combination has tripped the protection circuit before. As for schematic of the shower unit, it is quite literally a motor and switch in series, nothing else.